# Arrange JSON data by date within React--nothing breaks and nothing works

Tags: json, reactjs, sorting

I have found a few answers on Stack Overflow for this, but they have not worked within my code. Currently I have a JSON file which contains a `News` array. Each object has a title, description, and date. The sorting does not work, but it also does not currently break the page, so I'm not sure what to debug or what would help it work. Any help is much appreciated!

This is the code in my News.js file:

```
import labNewsJson from '../json/labNews.json';
import '../styles/News.css';

const newsList = labNewsJson['news']

class News extends Component {
    render() {
        newsList.sort ( function (a, b){
            return new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date);
        });

        const news = newsList.map((newsItem, index) => {
            return (
                <div className='newsContainer' key={index}>
                    <h3>{newsItem.title}</h3>
                    <p>{newsItem.description}</p>
                </div>
            )
        });

        return (
            <div className='container'>
                <div className='pageTitle'><h1>Lab News</h1></div>
                <div>{news}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default News;
```

Comment: Are your dates coming out as expected? I.e. does `new Date(a.date)` give you a date?

Comment: Did you parse the json ?Or you have something that does it automatically for you?

Comment: Coreyward--No, I'm getting NaN.

@ShyamBabu I tried, but I'm not sure how to parse only the date. I get errors when I try to JSON.parse the whole thing. I may be doing it incorrectly as well

Comment: What error did you get exactly?When trying parse?@Rgreaner

Comment: I'm sorry for the delayed response! I am able to get the dates by having different "month", "day", and "year" fields which I think will help those editing and don't know code within my project.